# How to set an HTML radio button using a JavaScript array variable

Tags: javascript, html

I have

```
<label for="gender" class="houseData">Male</label>
<input type="radio" id="houseGender" name="gender" class="houseData" value="Male"/>
<label for="gender" class="houseData">Female</label>
<input type="radio" id="houseGender" name="gender" class="houseData" value="Female"/>
```

and

```
document.getElementById("houseGender").value = house[houseID] [7];
```

where house[houseID] [7]; is either Male or Female.

When I do the above assignment, the radio button for gender is unchanged.

Any ideas as to how to fix this would be appreciated!

:-)

Answer (score 0):

The `id` attribute of an element must be unique. You have more than one element with id of `houseGender`.

You need to provide unique IDs to the two elements (say, `houseGenderMale` and `houseGenderFemale`). Then check the value that you want to assign, pick the right element, and set its `checked` property to `true`. For example:

```
document.getElementById("houseGenderMale").checked = 'true';
```